# How to resolve the shaking of the text in tailwind css?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js, tailwind-ui

When I hover the mouse pointer on any of the text, the text gets bold and then there is a `little shaking of the text`, how can we resolve that shaking of the text?

You can observe that behavior in the example given below also.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="p-30 bg-green-900">
   <div class="col-span-2 py-2 hidden sm:block">
            <div class="flex flex-row gap-3 justify-evenly items-center text-base sm:text-sm xl:text-xl leading-4">
              <li class="list-none text-slate-200 hover:text-white hover:opacity-100 hover:font-bold">
                <Link href="/">Home</Link>
              </li>
              <li class="list-none text-slate-200 hover:text-white hover:opacity-100 hover:font-bold">
                <Link href="/about">About</Link>
              </li>
              <li class="list-none text-slate-200 hover:text-white hover:opacity-100 hover:font-bold">
                <Link href="/projects">Projects</Link>
              </li>
              <li class="list-none text-slate-200 hover:text-white hover:opacity-100 hover:font-bold">
                <Link href="/blogs">Blogs</Link>
              </li>
            </div>
          </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### You can refer to this link if code snippet does not work

[link here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/RicOUlXtmU)

Comment: When you change the font weight, it causes a repaint because the layout is changed. The thickness of the glyph increases which causes the layout to jitter. There isn’t much you can do about it, unless you fix the element a fixed width. This is not a tailwind specific issue.

Comment: (Note to potential answerers: click **Run code snippet** and then **Full page** to see OP's menu.)

Comment: So is there any concrete solution to this? @Terry

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is using the opacity property on the hover event. I advise you to use hover:text-opacity-[] instead of hover:opacity-[] in text nodes. With such a replacement, everything works out perfectly and without twitching the text.